# manage 2 wireless device

Tags: wireless

I erased Windows 7 and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Latitude E4200.

I an very happy with my choice but with little pity.

I cannot use the wireless service in my university as the build-in device works unstable. I bought a USB wireless device, which solve the problem.

However, the build-in device keep to sent me message about unable to connect, which waste laptop's cup & battery.

The phsical bottom to turn off wireless affect both devices.

So the question is: "How can I manually shut down wireless device?"

There is another interest comes to my mind: "Does 2 wireless improve the overall internet usage if I run a high-internet-consuming program like BT ?"

Thank for your time and energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect like you normally would (don't worry about the other complaining about not being able to connect for now). Now, open a terminal and type `ifconfig`.

It should show you your network devices. You'll see `lo`, `eth0`, `wlan0`, `wlan1`. Look for the `wlan` that actually has an IP address...this is the one that you want to keep.

So, if `wlan1` has the IP, then we want to get rid of `wlan0`.

Now, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and scroll down to the very bottom, and just above `"exit 0"`, type

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then `ENTER` to save and exit. On reboot, it should take down the `wlan0` interface (the wireless card you don't want) as it starts up.

If later on you decide you want to turn this off, just erase that line.